# Calling an executable file with execlp in C

Tags: c, exec

In my program, I want to execute the code of a file with execlp() but I'm having some troubles.

Let pretend I have a file test.c containing a function f():

```
void f(void){
    print("test");
}
```

In my main programm, I want to call execlp to execute the function `f()` from the file test. 
I tried

```
execlp("test", "test", NULL);
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: [`execlp`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/execlp) function will load a program to replace the current running program. You cannot "call" a c file from another C program. May be you want to create a library?

Comment: I forgot to precise that my file test.c is already compiled and I have an executable file test.o in the same repertory as my main program. I simplified my problem but I would like to replace my code with the code on the test.c and not simply call the function  f()

Comment: Is `test.o` an executable or an object file?  On the command line, can you run it as `./test.o`?

Comment: Yeah, sorry: test.o is obviously not my executable file, I meant test.exe and also my test.c file contains a main who is executing indefinitely my f() function

Comment: Please update the question with the information about how your function `f()` is built into its own program (preferably not one called `test`) and compiled and linked etc.  People should not have to read through the comments to find the crucial information.

Comment: If the executable is "test.exe" then why are you trying to execute "test?

Answer (score 0):

`execlp()` is meant to execute binary executables, not source code.  If you want to run function `f()` from another file, you would simply include it in your source during compilation.

Comment: I forgot to precise that my file test.c is already compiled and I have an executable file test.o in the same repertory as my main program. I simplified my problem but I would like to replace my code with the code on the test.c and not simply call the function  'f()'

Comment: If you know the function header, and it sounds like you do, you can just forward declare it with `void f(void);` and link with test.o.

Comment: Something named `test.o` is usually not a fully-linked executable or library. It's just one component of such a thing. The way C works is you actually *do* just call `f()` if *and only if* the function is linked in (static or dynamic) with the final executable.

Comment: Yeah, sorry: test.o is obviously not my executable file, I meant test.exe and also my test.c file contains a main who is executing indefinitely my f() function. So I don't just want to simply use the function f() on my program

Comment: @AliT If it's `test.exe` then change `"test" to `"test.exe"` in the program.

Comment: You'll probably be OK this time, but be aware, @AliT, that `test` is a bad name to choose for a test program because the Unix shells have a built-in program `test` which is likely to be executed in preference to your program named `test`.  You may also get away with it better on Windows than you would on Unix.  Generally, though, your life will be easier (more reliable, less exasperating) if you stay clear of `test` as a program name.

Answer (score 0):

You need a `main()` function in the executable.

```
void f(void){
    print("test");
}

int main() {
    f();
    return 0;
}
```

When you run an executable, it always starts at the `main()` function.

Also, you should use the full pathname to the executable when you call `execlp()`:

```
execlp("./test", "test", (char *)NULL);
```

You need `./` at the beginning because `.` is not normally in the `$PATH` variable. So instead it's probably executing `/bin/test`.

Comment: My executable now looks like this: int main() { while(1) { f(); } return 0; } but I still cannot call the executable from my main program with execlp("test", "test", NULL)

Comment: Use `./test` instead of just `test`.